# Why was Dolly on the Island of Misfit Toys?

Tags: plot-explanation, rudolph-rednosed-reindeer

When watching [***Rudolph the Red-Nosed Reindeer***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rudolph_the_Red-Nosed_Reindeer_(TV_special)), all the toys on the island of misfit toys have some kind of production issues:

- a Spotted Elephant
- a bird that swims
- a cowboy that rides an ostrich
- a train with square wheels
- a boat that doesn't float
- etc, etc

Except Dolly the doll doesn't have any obvious defects.  Why was she on the island?

Comment: She contained a lot of lead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the voice casting list on [Rudolph the Red-Nosed Reindeer (TV special)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rudolph_the_Red-Nosed_Reindeer_(TV_special)), there is the following note:

> Corinne Conley voices Dolly, a seemingly normal girl rag doll on the Island of Misfit Toys. Her misfit problem is never explained on the special; many decades later, on NPR's Wait Wait… Don't Tell Me! news quiz show (broadcast December 8, 2007), Rudolph's producer, Arthur Rankin Jr., noted that Dolly's problem was psychological, caused by being abandoned by her owner (named as Sue in the special) and suffering depression from feeling uncared-for.